# How can I adjust steer angle based on speed in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I'm following this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAEpLX3rfms) video on how to make a car in Unity. But my car doesn't lower the steering angle based on the speed of the video. The idea was that you can steer the car at a max of 50 degrees at the slowest and then 10 degrees at the fastest. But it's having no effect on the car. Could someone show me how to fix this?

Code:

```
public WheelCollider wheelFL;
public WheelCollider wheelFR;
public WheelCollider wheelRL;
public WheelCollider wheelRR;

public Transform wheelFL_Trans;
public Transform wheelFR_Trans;
public Transform wheelRL_Trans;
public Transform wheelRR_Trans;

public float lowSpeedSteerAngle;
public float highSpeedSteerAngle;
public float Torque;
public float centerOfMassHeight;

public float speed;
public GameObject speedometer;
public GameObject accelerator;
public GameObject brake;
public float pedalRotationFactor;
public float speedometerRotationFactor;
public float decelerationRate;

public float currentSpeed;
public float topSpeed;
public float maxReverseSpeed;

public GameObject trunk;
public Material[] brakeMaterials;

public float currentSteerAngle;
public float turnAmount;

private Vector3 com;
private Rigidbody rigidBody;
private float acceleratorSpeed;
private float brakeSpeed;

void Start () {
    rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    com = rigidBody.centerOfMass;
    com.y = centerOfMassHeight;
    rigidBody.centerOfMass = com;
}

void FixedUpdate () {
    currentSpeed = 2 * Mathf.PI * wheelFL.radius * wheelFL.rpm * 60 / 1000;
    if(currentSpeed < topSpeed && currentSpeed > -maxReverseSpeed){
        wheelFL.motorTorque = Torque * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        wheelFR.motorTorque = Torque * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        wheelRL.motorTorque = Torque * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        wheelRR.motorTorque = Torque * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    }else{
        wheelFL.motorTorque = 0;
        wheelFR.motorTorque = 0;
        wheelRL.motorTorque = 0;
        wheelRR.motorTorque = 0;
    }


    if(!Input.GetButton("Vertical")){
        wheelFL.brakeTorque = decelerationRate;
        wheelFR.brakeTorque = decelerationRate;
        wheelRL.brakeTorque = decelerationRate;
        wheelRR.brakeTorque = decelerationRate;
    }else{
        wheelFL.brakeTorque = 0;
        wheelFR.brakeTorque = 0;
        wheelRL.brakeTorque = 0;
        wheelRR.brakeTorque = 0;
    }

    if(Input.GetAxis("Vertical") < 0){
        //Changing The Materials
        Material[] mats = trunk.GetComponent<Renderer>().materials;
        mats[0] = brakeMaterials[1];

        trunk.GetComponent<Renderer>().materials = mats;
    }else{
        //Reseting The Materials
        Material[] mats = trunk.GetComponent<Renderer>().materials;
        mats[0] = brakeMaterials[0];

        trunk.GetComponent<Renderer>().materials = mats;
    }

    speed = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.magnitude * 15;
    float speedFactor = 1 - (GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.magnitude * 3.6f / topSpeed);
    currentSteerAngle = highSpeedSteerAngle + ((lowSpeedSteerAngle - highSpeedSteerAngle) * speedFactor);
    turnAmount = currentSteerAngle * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    wheelFL.steerAngle = turnAmount;
    wheelFR.steerAngle = turnAmount;
}

void Update () {
    wheelFL_Trans.Rotate(0, 0, wheelFL.rpm / 60 * 360 * Time.deltaTime);
    wheelFR_Trans.Rotate(0, 0, wheelFR.rpm / 60 * 360 * Time.deltaTime);
    wheelRL_Trans.Rotate(0, 0, wheelRL.rpm / 60 * 360 * Time.deltaTime);
    wheelRR_Trans.Rotate(0, 0, wheelRR.rpm / 60 * 360 * Time.deltaTime);

    Vector3 wheelSteerAngle = wheelFL_Trans.localEulerAngles;
    wheelSteerAngle.y = turnAmount + 90;
    wheelFL_Trans.localEulerAngles = wheelSteerAngle;
    wheelFR_Trans.localEulerAngles = wheelSteerAngle;

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P)){
        Vector3 resetPosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x, 1.5f, transform.position.z);
        Quaternion resetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, 0f);

        //Reseting Velocity
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);

        //Reseting Rotation
        transform.rotation = resetRotation;

        //Reseting Position
        transform.position = resetPosition;

        //Reseting Motor Torque and Steering Angle
        wheelFL.motorTorque = 0f;
        wheelFR.motorTorque = 0f;
        wheelRL.motorTorque = 0f;
        wheelRR.motorTorque = 0f;

        wheelFL.steerAngle = 0f;
        wheelFR.steerAngle = 0f;
        wheelRL.steerAngle = 0f;
        wheelRR.steerAngle = 0f;
    }

    acceleratorSpeed = wheelFL.motorTorque;
    brakeSpeed = wheelFL.motorTorque;

    if(acceleratorSpeed < 0){
        acceleratorSpeed = 0;
    }

    if(brakeSpeed > 0){
        brakeSpeed = 0;
    }

    if(speed >= 350){
        speed = 350;
    }

    speedometer.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(speed * speedometerRotationFactor - 100, 90f, 0f);
    accelerator.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(acceleratorSpeed * pedalRotationFactor, 0f, 0f);
    brake.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(brakeSpeed * pedalRotationFactor * -1, 0f, 0f);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you've set the maxSpeed in kmph or mph, yes? You should note that velocity.magnitude returns the speed in m/s, which needs to be converted to the unit which you are using for speed in your car script. If it is m/s to km/h, then you can multiply the velocity magnitude by 3.6. If it is m/s to miles/h then multiply the magnitude by 2.2369362920544. So your speedFactor will now be

```
float speedFactor = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.magnitude * 3.6f / maxSpeed; //or magnitude * 2.236936f for miles/h
```

Comment: No effect, the car still turns the same amount at high speed as it does at low speed.

Comment: What is the max speed of your car? And make currentSpeedAngle a public variable or Serialize it so that it shows in the inspector and then check its values. If it decreases to highSpeedSteerAngle at speeds getting closer to maxSpeed, then there's a problem in the physics or your controller. PS you aren't using input to regulate the steering?

Comment: Max speed is 40. And I just made the currentSpeedAngle public and the value was hovering around 30. I also did the same for the turnAmount (from the answer on gamedev). That was just back to square one; the values weren't effected by the speed. I've updated the code to what it is now by the way. Also, what do you mean by using input to regulate steering?

Comment: Using the input axes to control steering, just like you're doing for torque.

Comment: Oh yes I definitely am.

Comment: Make the variable speed be equal to the velocity magnitude * 3.6, and use that to calculate the speedFactor variable. Does the speed variable change in the inspector? And currentSpeed should be calculated in terms of the rigidbody's velocity, just like I said above.

Comment: The speed does change in the inspector. I tried using speed rather than speedFactor, I got the same effect and same values from it too.

Comment: I just noticed, the currentSteerAngle should actually be Mathf.Lerp(lowSpeedAngle, highSpeedAngle, speedFactor).

Comment: Yes I just changed that actually, still the same result

Comment: I just tried printing off turn amount to the console, I got the inverse of what I wanted, I could turn more as I speed up then when the car was at a low speed. I then tried to switch the values of the highSpeedAngle and lowSpeedAngle and then it was the same at low and high speed with an angle of about 30...

Comment: Don't do that, instead remove the "1 - " before the speedFactor calculation, and use the Lerp statement I used above. Should definitely work now.

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert at unity, but it looks like

```
public float lowSpeedSteerAngle;
public float highSpeedSteerAngle;
```

May be your problem. Unless I am missing something, these variables are declared and then called without any value being assigned to them.

Comment: The values of those are assigned in the inspector, the high speed one is 10 and the other is 30.

Comment: Before you made an edit, you had  
`currentSteerAngle = Mathf.Lerp(highSpeedSteerAngle,lowSpeedSteerAngle,speedFactor)`


Your angles are in the wrong order. They should be   `Mathf.Lerp(lowSPeedSteerAngle, highSpeedSteerAngle, speedFactor)`

What sort of results do you get back from speedFactor?  
With your current formula of
`currentSteerAngle = highSpeedSteerAngle + ((lowSpeedSteerAngle - highSpeedSteerAngle) * speedFactor);`

If speed factor is between 0 and 1, then at full speed you would return an angle of 30. 

@MatthewInglis

Comment: Speed factor starts of at around 1 at low speed and moves down to about 0 at high speed.